# get text from textfield in dynamic tableview and insert it in array swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I am trying to get the text from textfield in dynamic tableview so thats mean i have one or more textfield i tried this but its not working

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GPACell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    coursesGrade.insert(cell.grade.text!, at: indexPath.row)

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `textField.tag` and `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate of `UITextFieldDelegate`

make a array to storing textfield text. for every `textField` that added to table you have to add an empty value in array data and set table `indexPath.row` as `textField.tag`

so in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate you have access to `textField.tag` and you can store `textField.text` to `data[textField.tag]` array.

there are a lot of ways to make it work. It's one of that ways ;-)

Comment: Using the `tag` property to store index path information is very fragile and liable to break. You can get the index path of any cell by calling: `indexPath(for:)` on the `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`

Comment: @RoboticCat, I don't thing so, I used `Tag` in some project and that was success. I'm introducing that tools (Tag, textField delegate), so he/she can use these to make it done.

Comment: It's fragile because you have no control over the property (other code might overwrite the tag), moving cells will cause the property to be the wrong value without writing and maintaining extra code, doesn't easily support sections & row/items, can easily cause run-time exceptions, is hard to debug (whereas properties / references just appear in LLDB and code using it is not compile-time checked for correctness. Using the `tag` property is an anti-pattern because of all these reasons and more. If you search the internet for `iOS tag property fragile` (or similar) you will find examples

Comment: Sorry I don't get it